# Let $a_1, a_2 ,a_3 \dots$ be a sequence of real numbers such that:

Tags: sequences-and-series

The question is:

Let $a_1, a_2 ,a_3 \dots$ be a  sequence of real numbers such that:
$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$

For any real number $x$, define an integer valued function, $ f(x)$ , as the smallest  positive integer $n$ for which $a_n \geq x$. Then for any integer $n\geq 1$ :

a.$f(a_n) \leq n$

b.$f(a_n) \geq n$

My Solution:

By the function definition, for $f(x) = w \implies a_w \geq x$

If we look at at option a, and assume $f(a_n) \leq n$. I get the following results:

Let $f(a_n) = z$.
Then from our assumption, $ z \leq n$.

Now from function definition, $a_z \geq a_n$.
Then combining, $a_z \geq a_n$ <=> $ z \leq n$.

Then $ a_1 \geq a_2 \geq a_3 \dots$. Then the initial condition that  $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$ doesn't hold true. So our initial assumption is wrong.
So option A is wrong. And option B is correct, going by the same method. The answer given is A, and I don't understand what's wrong about my solution.

Comment: Well...it is certainly true that $a_n≥a_n$.  So the only question is "Is $n$ the *smallest* index $k$  such that $a_k≥a_n$"?  Of course that doesn't have to be the case, and where it fails, we'd have $f(a_n)<n$.

Comment: To see that option $B$ can fail to hold, consider the sequence $\{10,1,10, 11, 12, 13, \cdots \}$.  Then $a_1=a_3=10$.  We have $f(10)=f(a_3)=1$ since $a_1=10≥10$ and $1$ is the least such natural number.

Comment: Please make a more-informative title... not just the first words of your question (which tell us little about the question itself).

Comment: Do you mean $a_n\ge f(x)$?

Comment: The precise erroneous step in your solution is "Then combining, $a_z\ge a_n\Leftrightarrow z\le n$". You only proved (assuming option a) that both hold in the particular case $z=f(a_n)$, but not that they are equivalent.

Comment: @AnneBauval Could you elaborate on what you mean by "both hold in the particular case$ z=f(a_n),$ but not that they are equivalent." I am not able to understand

Comment: @PNT The question is correct, they have stated $a_n \geq x$

Comment: @lulu Thank you, i understand why option B is incorrect.

Comment: You proved that *if* $z=f(a_n)$ then $a_z\ge a_n$ (by definition of $f$) *and* $z\le n$ (by assuming a). You (unsurprisingly) did not prove that for *any* integers $z,n:$ $a_z\ge a_n\Leftrightarrow z\le n.$